# Changing value in class from form and reading it from another class, possible?

Tags: c#

I must admit I'm quite the beginner as far as coding goes.

Right now I want to change a `boolean` value in a `class` by pressing a button in the `Main Form`.

But I also want to read the changed value from another class.

Is this even possible ? I'm using `C#` btw.

Because right now I have the problem that using `Class1 class = new Class1();` creates unique versions of the class for the form1 and the class calling it.

Comment: Are you wanting all instances of that class to share the change of your boolean variable's state i.e if it's true or false?

Comment: Can you show us some code that you tried? or the `class` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try two options

**1. Using static Property:**
 By using a [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property only one copy of it exists and its not object specific.

**Example:**

```
public class Class1
{
    public static bool MyBoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You could use it as

```
        //Set value 
        Class1.MyBoolProperty = true;

        //Get value
        var currentBoolVal = Class1.MyBoolProperty;
```

**2. Using singleton instance:** Here only one object is created.

**Example:**

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class1()
    {
    }

    private static Class1 _object;

    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_object == null)
                _object = new Class1();
            return _object;
        }
    }

    public bool MyBoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You could use it as:

```
        //Set value
        Class1.Instance.MyBoolProperty = true;

        //Get value
        var currentBoolVal = Class1.Instance.MyBoolProperty;
```

Comment: It worked nicely. I didn't know you could set functions and variables in classes to static and they would be the same for everyone accessing them. Thank you!

Comment: @NicoleBauer: Hi, If there are no more open questions, you could mark it as answered..